# posting user input to Web Page permanently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

What would be the best way to get text input from a user then display that on the webpage permanently? I'm still new to html / css / JavaScript and any recommendations of a good book are much appreciated,  thanks.

Comment: Provide more context. It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: What have you tried? Have an input/textarea wrapped in form. Handle the post by taking the value and storing it in the database. on the website, read the value from db and display it.

Answer (score 1):

HTML and CSS are only parts to describe how the Page will be rendered. The JavaScript can be seen as Tool to manipulate Content while the page is Displayed, or handle some Events.

However to load Content oder Store data, you need a Database or a File Storage (more likely database) and send Informations to that. This is most commonly done with MYSQL and PHP. 
A chat could also be done With Redis, which is also an Database but only for key value pairs.
Redis needs a bit more Knowledge in Use, but can be verry powerful for stuff like a simple Shoutbox. (also more complex usage possible)